# how to separate per 8 digit from string in c#?

Tags: c#

```
string txte = save.ToString();

for (int i = 7; i < save.Length; i= i+8)
{
    outs.Append(txte.Substring(i-7,i)+ " ");
}
```

Comment: Can you share example input/output ?

Comment: Can you flesh out your code (for example showing what `save` and `outs` are (type and value) and explaining what you are trying to do (example *"I have the string "elephant" and I want to convert it to "giraffe" using a fourier transform"*)

Comment: These are articles in Japanese, but it might be helpful.[【C#】文字列を指定した文字数で分割する拡張メソッド](http://baba-s.hatenablog.com/entry/2015/03/19/140748), [【C#入門】String.Splitで文字列を分割(複数文字、文字数でも分割)](https://www.sejuku.net/blog/44242)

Comment: @AnuViswan example txt = 1111000011111000, output = 11110000 11111000

Comment: what if 11110000111110 ? that is, total number of digits is not a multiple of 8

Comment: Edit your question, adding your comments and declarations examples to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Given**

```
public static class Extension
{
   public static IEnumerable<string> Chunks(this string input, int size)
      // select with index
      => input?.Select((x, i) => i) 
               // filter by chunk
               .Where(i => i % size == 0)  
               // substring out the chunk, or part thereof
               .Select(i => input.Substring(i, Math.Min(size,input.Length - i)));
}
```

**Usage**

```
var s = "11111111222222223333333344444444";

foreach (var result in s.Chunks(8))
   Console.WriteLine(result);

Console.WriteLine("---");

// or add space
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", s.Chunks(8)));
```

**Results**

```
11111111
22222222
33333333
44444444
---
11111111 22222222 33333333 44444444
```

Answer (score 1):

As long as you are sure your input has a length which is the exact multiple of 8 characters then this works easily:

```
var output =
    String.Join(
        " ",
        Enumerable.Range(0, txt.Length / 8).Select(x => txt.Substring(x * 8, 8)));
```

If you need to ensure that the input has a length which is the multiple of 8 then do this first:

```
txt = txt.PadRight(txt.Length + txt.Length % 8 == 0 ? 0 : 8 - txt.Length % 8);
```